# Stieltjes Transform of random sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, soft-question, real-numbers

I am trying to understand Stieltzes transform( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_transformation). I see it's connections to moments under certain conditions.

Consider a vector of real positive numbers. Under this broad condition is there any one-to-one correspondence between Stieltjes transform and it's inverse? For example for the same sequence we can perform Fourier transform and next by performing inverse Fourier we can  get back the numbers. Is the same possible with Stieltjes transform? If so is there significance of Siteltjes transform (for Fourier it says about the frequencies)?

Comment: Are you wanting to find $\rho$ from $\int_{I}\frac{\rho(t)dt}{t-z}$, or to find $\rho$ from $\int_{I}t^n\rho(t)dt$?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Thanks for your interest. Actually, neither. I understand that if all finite moments exist Stieltjes transform is very helpful.  But I am trying to see the transform's behavior for any random real sequences. My specific interest is to analyse a signal/sequence from Gaussian in Steiltjes transform domain like we do in Fourier. Not sure if it is useful or possible.